# how to prepopulate a flexifield in form_alter?

Tags: entities

I have a flexifield with name:

```
field_flexi_pricing[0][value][field_pricing_day_price][0][value]
```

how do i fill in a default value for this flexifield in `form_alter`?

Answer (score 1):

do a form alter and add your value as a default value using the default value key,

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/5#textfield

```
'#default_value' => //my value;
```

you can always print $form in your form_alter after you have altered your $form, to have a better look at your flexifield array, and chck if the default value is set like it is shown in the forms api reference link above. :)